# Sorting dates and display the recent ones VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following list, I want to sort the dates and display the recent ones and stock them in ranges 21 and 22 like this:

[image]

I have successfully written this code that helped to do the sorting and display the recent dates and stock them on range 21, now I am stack and I dont know how to do to display the end date associated to each recent date.

```
 Loop Until Not ech

      ' conversion of numbers into text for dico and  listbox)
      ' and the false dates (written in text) to real dates
      On Error GoTo PasDate
      For i = 2 To UBound(t)
         t(i, 1) = CStr(t(i, 1))
         If TypeName(t(i, 2)) = "String" Then t(i, 2) = 1 * DateSerial(Right(t(i, 2), 4), Mid(t(i, 2), 4, 2), Left(t(i, 2), 2))
      Next i
      On Error Resume Next

      'Fill dico
      Set dico = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
      dico.CompareMode = TextCompare
      For i = 2 To UBound(t)
         If t(i, 1) <> "" Then
            If Not dico.Exists(t(i, 1)) Then
               dico.Add t(i, 1), t(i, 2)
            Else
               If t(i, 2) > dico(t(i, 1)) Then dico(t(i, 1)) = t(i, 2)
            End If
         End If
      Next i

   'Transfert dico to the table  r for the list
   ReDim r(1 To dico.Count, 1 To 2): i = 0
   For Each x In dico.Keys: i = i + 1: r(i, 1) = x: r(i, 2) = dico(x): Next

   'fill ranges 20 and 21 
   .Range("b20:b21").Resize(, Columns.Count - 1).Clear

   .Range("b20").Resize(1, UBound(r)).HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
   .Range("b21").Resize(1, UBound(r)).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
   .Range("b20").Resize(2, UBound(r)).Borders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
   .Range("b20:b21").Resize(2, UBound(r)) = Application.Transpose(r)

   End With

   'poplate the listbox
    For i = 1 To UBound(r): r(i, 1) = Format(r(i, 2), "dd/mm/yyyy"): Next

   'For i = 1 To UBound(r): r(i, 1) = Format(r(i, 1), "000"): r(i, 2) = Format(r(i, 2), "dd/mm/yyyy"): Next

   With ListBox1
      .ColumnCount = 2
      .ColumnHeads = False
      .ColumnWidths = .Width * 0.7        '& ";" & .Width * (1 - 0.6 + 0.1)
      .List = r
   End With
   Exit Sub

'
PasDate:
Exit Sub
   End
End Sub
```

Comment: How about a simple `Match` followed by `Offset`?

Comment: How can I do that ?